# Add column containing filename to a batch of .csv files in mac OSX

Tags: csv

I've got 300 .csv files. I need to add a column that contains the filename in each row. I'm new to using command line in terminal. I've looked around but haven't found code I understand for doing this in mac. Would be very grateful for help

Comment: Have you looked at automator or applescript?

Comment: You have 300 CSV files and in each of those files you want to add the name of the file to every single line? Seems a little pointless - is that correct? How about an example that shows before and after so we can see where you added it (start or end of line) and what separator you use?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a bash-script:

vi csv-script.sh

press i (for inserting text)

copy/paste this code as example (is kind of self-explaining):

```
    #!/bin/bash

    for file in $(find ./  -maxdepth 1 -name '*.csv' -type f)
    do
        touch tmp
        for line in $(cat $file)
        do
            fileCol="${file:3}"
            echo "${fileCol};${line}" >>tmp
        done
        mv -f tmp $file
        rm -f tmp
    done
```

change the semicolon within the echo-command to whatever separator you need.

press esc and press colon :wq

then call from cli with:. csv-script.sh. (pay attention to dot space csv-script.sh)

have a try.